# Discarding UDP with specific header in layer 3

Tags: linux, udp, ip, voip

I'm implementing a setup in which I receive **duplicate** datagrams in a video-streaming based on UDP. I noticed that in layer 3 (IP) there's a header field named **identification** in which I can use to detect duplicated frames. The problem is that duplicated frames reach the top of the TCP/IP (Application Layer) stack and consequently create conflict with streaming.

Now my question, ¿How can I discard datagrams, in the receiving station, by detecting duplicates in the identification field until it reaches the application layer, using linux?

Comment: The layer 3 ID field is used for matching the fragments of a fragmented datagram. It might not even be filled in if the datagram is not fragmented.

Comment: See [RFC 6864](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6864) for more details about this field.

Comment: Are there no sequence or frame numbers or timestamps associated with the video data?

Comment: To Barmar: Well RFC 6864 says "The IPv4 ID field is no longer permitted to be used for duplicate detection.  This applies to both atomic and non-atomic datagrams." So I can't rely on that field :(

Comment: To Ben: MPEG-TS use the 13818-1 IOS/IEC standard in which use the field Continuity Counter (CC): a 4 bit number used for detecting lost frames. There's also other interesting fields. But suppose that I found something that I can use for detecting duplicated datagrams, what can I do for discarding those until the app use it?